# Hibernate Mapping

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables, intially i have n't define any kind of relation ship between two tables.
after inserting data into tables then, there is possibilty of relation ship may existed two tables. May i come to know that relation ship.
If T1 contains single entry but same entry two times appreared into table T2. then relation ship is one-to-many relationship? If anybody know please reply me....

Regards,
Vijay.

Comment: can you rephrase that or be more specific. I don't understand what you are tryingt to say

Answer (score 0):

Usually relationships between tables are spelled out using foreign key relationships that are built into the child table.  Your Hibernate mapping should reflect those.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - relationship would be 1 to Many and you will have to put a mechanism to identify that. The standard practice is to have a foreign key column in table 2 which would be the primary key of table 1.

Hope that helps.